# recovering a broken GNOME-desktop in debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

an hour ago I had a working gnome-desktop on my debian system (thinkpad x121e).

Then I installed compiz that crashed.

After a reboot the gnome-desktop no longer started.

Then I did some upgrades with aptitude, all gnome-packages seem to be there, but it is still not working.

On startup I get a login-dialog, when I login there is no desktop, only some window-manager running that allows me to start a terminal.

When I run "gnome-session" I get the error message "failed to load session "gnome".

So how do I get back to a working desktop?

I have tried "tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install" but that just displays a progress window that after half an hour still shows 0%.

Can someone help me please?

I have tried "

Answer (score 11):

Try doing this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade #see if the package is held back
sudo apt-get purge gnome-session
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
startx
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10783266&postcount=5

Answer (score 6):

first of all `sudo apt-get purge gnome-session`.

after all purging the gnome session make sure to clear packages by using bellow command
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
`sudo apt-get autoclean`

and than `sudo apt-get install gnome-session`
it will work most the time when tasksel fail to install gnome.

i have tested this code on debian jessie and ubuntu lts 14.04.

i have this kind of crazy issue once i have messed up with gtk or multiple session at a time So also.

this will help you out form the session issue.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading from Squeeze to Wheezy a virtual machine running on KVM, I had to install "gnome-session-falback" in order to open successfully a session in gnome:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install aptitude and tasksel before install gnome

Aptitude is an Ncurses based FrontEnd to Apt, the debian package manager.

Tasksel is a tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated “task” onto your system.

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
```

Install gnome on debian

```
# tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```

from http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I was missing Xorg. Installed it with this;

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody reaches this question, while investigating the similar issue when login-page wasn't even showing in `gnome 3`, go to recovery mode, and select "resume" (which will lead you to the terminal of your user), or hit `alt` + `F2` if are on the actual blank screen (which will bring out terminal) and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
```

(depending on your current configuration, you might need to change `gdm3` with `lightdm`)

Seems like, for whatever reason, this package got uninstalled.

If you have it already installed, and it is not working correctly, you can call before the above command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```